# Failing to delete my account

Tags: facebook, yahoo-mail

I want to permanently delete my facebook account, but it doesn't allow me despite me putting in the correct password! Kindly help me

Comment: @pnuts - that was nearly three years ago!

Comment: @pnuts - if you think I got the closure wrong, then please raise a custom flag and another mod will review it.

Answer (score 0):

Guessing it is the tag that is wrong in this case, log in to your **FB account** and then go to https://www.facebook.com/help/delete_account?rdrhc.